# Agregar Where opcional a Select dentro de Función

Tags: php

Tengo que hallar el valor máximo de un campo en diferentes tablas. Para ello utilizo la siguiente función:

```
<?php
function ObtenerMax($campo, $tabla, $campoW, $valor){
    $BD = new ConexionDB();
    $sql = "SELECT max($campo) as valorId FROM $tabla WHERE $campoW = $valor";
    $sth = $BD->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();

    $valor   = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $valorId = intval($valor['valorId']) + 1;
    return $valorId;
}
// Desde aquí se invoca a la función y cambia el campo y la tabla
$c = 'numero';
$t = 'personal';
$w = 'tipo';
$v = 'A';
echo ObtenerMax($c, $t, $w, $v);
?>
```

Tengo dos preguntas:

1. Funciona si tengo que utilizar el `Where`, pero qué debo modificar
   en    caso no necesite utilizar el `Where`? Nota: El campo
   Tipo es varchar(1).
2. Si tengo que utilizar el resultado de la función en un insert en la
   misma tabla, debo invocar nuevamente la conexión a la base de datos
   ($BD = new ConexionDB();) ?.

Comment: y si pones un `if` preguntando si la variable `$valor` es valida en caso verdadero dejas la consulta como esta en caso contrario le quitas el where a la consulta.
la otra seria mandarle al parametro `$valor` lo mismo que al parametro `$campoW`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrías que tener en cuenta algunas validaciones dentro de la función, lo del `Where` podrías validar que que valor de `campoW` **no esté vacío**. `if(strlen($campoW) != 0)` sí no lo está concatenamos el `where` de la consulta.

Otro punto a tener en cuenta es los valores que se envían en el `where`. `números o cadenas` los más comunes. sí no es `Integer` ni `Double` añadimos las comillas al valor , esto haciendo uso de la función [gettype](http://php.net/manual/es/function.gettype.php)

```
if(gettype($valor)!='integer'and gettype($valor)!='double')
        $valor = "'".$valor."'";
```

el Código final podría parecer a esto

```
function ObtenerMax($campo, $tabla, $campoW, $valor){
      if(gettype($valor)!='integer'and gettype($valor)!='double')
          $valor = "'".$valor."'";
      $sql = "SELECT max($campo) as valorId FROM $tabla " ;
      /* Verificamos el campo , si viene vacío no concatenamos , caso contrario Sí*/
      if(strlen($campoW) != 0)  $sql.= "WHERE $campoW = $valor";
      $sth = $BD->prepare($sql);
      $sth->execute();

      $valor   = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $valorId = intval($valor['valorId']) + 1;
      return $valorId;
 }
$c = 'numero';
$t = 'personal';
$w = 'tipo';
$v = 'A';
echo ObtenerMax($c, $t, $w, $v);
```

Comment: Para invocar la función los campos $w y $v deben ir = ''; o no se envían?

Comment: Debe enviar los parámetros esperados. Si no le dará error. Puede enviar vacío o null. De preferencia vacío.  **" "**

Comment: $valor puede ser String o Integer. El primer if solo valida si $valor es String. No hay otra forma de quitarle las comillas?

Comment: Así es. Válida que sea `String` si es así le añade las comillas caso contrario no

Comment: Pero si $valor es Integer también funciona.

Comment: Sí, funciona bien. Si no es así comentar